# geth is not attached with JavaScript console

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, golang

I am Nikhil Upadhyay I am trying to **connect geth with javaScript Console** but it didn't  work for me
here are few steps which I already tried but could not resolve it

**geth attach ipc:gethDataDir/ geth.ipc**

I have also tried with IP and port address as well but it did not also work for me

**geth attach http://myip:port**

**geth version:**

Geth
Version: 1.10.8-stable
Git Commit: 26675454bf93bf904be7a43cce6b3f550115ff90
Architecture: amd64
Go Version: go1.16.4
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=/home/nikhil/go_projects
GOROOT=go

The error I got: **Fatal: Failed to start the JavaScript console: API modules: Post "http://myip address": connect: connection refused**

can anyone help me with this...

Comment: did you add `--http` `--http.port` and stuff like that?

Comment: No, can you please explain more about it how can I  use  **--http --http.port**  it.

Comment: I have tried but it did not work for me... thanks